# Deleting MySQL database with a "-" in the name

Tags: linux, mysql

One member of the dev team managed to create one databases with a "-" in the name with a remote graphical interface (and *I think* the second one is a legacy DB).

I am trying to remove both of them with the

```
DROP DATABASE "dbname-a";
```

command inside the `mysql` command line interface, however I am getting back the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"dbname-a"' at line 1

I tried using the db name with and without "", and also inside ' '. all variations presented the same syntax error.

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct way to do this would be with backtick quoting. For example:

```
DROP DATABASE `dbname-a`
```

This true for [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as well. Lots more info on this Stack Overflow post - [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had the feeling I was missing something.

Comment: This catches a lot of developers, even experienced ones.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to delete it in the command line, as in:

```
mysqladmin drop "dbname-a"
```

From [Oracle 5.7 Reference Manual - mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html)

> drop db_name
>
> Delete the database named db_name and all its tables.